# Website weirdly broken

Tags: html, css, developer-tools

`Hello,`

I have the website DaltonEmpire (http://daltonempire.nl, check out for yourself), and when I got home today, it showed error 500. I had made really tiny HTML changes at school via my new CodeAnywhere app, but this was not supposed to happen. After some cleaning up of my PHP, **just removing whitespaces**, the page loaded.

- But now, the background is completely gone and there all all kinds of weird `&nspb;` tags between my HTML according to Chrome Developer Tools [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTq5A.png)], **which weren't there before.** In my actual code, of course there's whitespace to order my HTML, but that's just spaces, no `&nspb;`'s, and that never happened before.
- Also, the `body` background is not loaded [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Mlb.png)], and the Developer Tools indicate that CSS responsible for the background is not included at all [[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG1rr.png)] (rather than overwritten or not loaded), even though it is clearly in a `<style>` block with the `body` selector [[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EThFa.png)]. Manually adding that [[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRDfj.png)][[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkZn4.jpg)] bit through the Developer Tools seem to fix this.

---

Has anyone any idea how this could happen/how this could be solved?
The strangest thing is, I did not change anything specific at all that I can recall. What has caused this?

I need my website to be fixed as fast as possible, as my visitors are students to get their educative documents and in two days is their test week.

Thanks in regard,

Isaiah van Hunen

---

*Attachments:*

1. Weird &nspb;'s
   [image: Weird &nspb;'s]
2. Background not loaded
   [image: Background not loaded]
3. Background CSS not included?
   [image: Background CSS not included]
4. Background CSS *is* included
   [image: CSS is included]
5. Adding manual Background CSS
   [image: Adding manual Background CSS]
6. Background loads
   [image: Background loads]

Comment: If your website is coded in PHP, showing us the rendered HTML isn't going to help, we would need to see the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help with 1).

`&nbsp;` is a formatting entity:

> it is the entity used to represent a non-breaking space. It is essentially a  standard space, the primary difference being that a browser should not break 
>   (or wrap) a line of text at the point that this `&nbsp;` occupies.

http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/www_faq/nbsp.html

Microsoft Word puts it into HTML files, and so do other WYSIWYG editors.

Unfortunately, CodeAnywhere seems to have the same issue.

Do you have an earlier version of the code that you can open in Notepad/Notepad++/Atom in order to add the whitespace manually there (with `
 tags or the like)? That might help.

Comment: Hi & thanks, hmm that's stupid. If I edit my homepage in Coda 2, it shows nothing like `&nbsp;` at all and that is the live document. In my directadmin, editing the page shows `Â ` all over the place, is that what you mean? I don't have Windows and thus not those programs, but I've got textEdit. However, I do not exactly understand what am I supposed to do.. :]

Comment: First I tried to delete all the `Â `, but that broke the website. Replacing the `Â ` with ` ` totally fixed it, however! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad your problem was solved! I think it's a cross-OS issue with certain software, and any plain text editor would fix it.